# Change image src from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dom

I have been trying a lot of different ways to make a change on a image src from a AJAX Requset, the new URL is retrived from an AJAX call, with the Developer Tools i visualized data the returning variable 'DATA'  have the expected URL but the image SRC get this:

"atrk.js-; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode"

---

The AJAX Request:

```
$.post("readurl.php",function(data){
      $("#imagen").attr("src",data);     
 });
```

The HTML Element:

```
<img id="imagen" src="old_pic.png">
```

The PHP file:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("links.xml");
echo $xml->URL_one;
?>
```

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked what's in the links.xml?

Comment: check the content of links.xml make sure it is not a js file. second, after changing the source trigger to load event of the image to renew the view.

Comment: Of Course, i get the expected URL and i can put it on on p.innerHTML but cannot in the img.src.

Comment: links.xml is my own file:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LINKS>  
  <URL_one>globe.png</URL_one>  
</LINKS>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use prop function:

```
$("#imagen").prop("src",data);
```

Comment: what do you see if you open the chrome inspector, on network tab, and click on the request that this code makes?

Comment: and on console tab of chrome inspector, this got some error?

Comment: and on elements tab, how stays this element after request?